# C# shorthand switch statement

Tags: c#

Is there any shorter way to shorten this switch statement? Ps: I've been looking everywhere but all end-up with the complex one.

Here's the code:

```cs
switch (type)
{
    default: case 1: Type = "MANUAL"; break;
    case 2: Type = "SELF DECOUPLING"; break;
    case 3: Type = "AUTO"; break;
    case 4: Type = "SEMI PNEUMATIC"; break;
}
```

Comment: Put it into a function. Otherwise I'd even add more line breaks to maintain a better readability. Another way to do this is by using a class or static function like `Type.GetFromInt(type)`.

Comment: Any reason why do you want to shorten it? Also, it looks like you might need an `enum`.

Comment: @41686d6564 I just like things to be shortened.

Comment: Sure ill try @ChrᴉzsupportsMonica

Comment: If it's only for returning a string I'd suggest using a ```Dictionary<int, string>``` instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't get much shorter, but you can use a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) introduced in *C# 8.0*, which may save you a couple of *printable characters*:

```
public string SomeMethod(int type)
    => type switch
    {
       2 => "SELF DECOUPLING",
       3 => "AUTO",
       4 => "SEMI PNEUMATIC",
       _ => "MANUAL"
    };
```

Or an *if then else*:

```
if (type == 2) Type = "SELF DECOUPLING";
else if (type == 3) Type = "AUTO";
else if (type == 4) Type = "SEMI PNEUMATIC";
else Type = "MANUAL";
```

Comment: Couldn't you also remove the first case (i.e. 1), and let that fallback onto the default case?

Comment: @Hayden yup just noticed that, thanks

Comment: Wow that was quick, really helpful!

Comment: @HadifHatta fingers were at the ready

Comment: Instead of "if then else", I would go with a ternary operator: `Type = type == 2 ? "SELF DECOUPLING" : type == 3 ? "AUTO" : type == 4 ? "SEMI PNEUMATIC" : "MANUAL";`. Could be broken into several lines to look nicer. Although I disagree with the OP on shortening the code just for the sake of shortening it.

Comment: @41686d6564 you are right that should probably added for completness, thanks